# How to disable Tern synchronization in Eclipse Luna?

Tags: javascript, eclipse, tern

I use Eclipse Luna SP2 for Java EE for some JavaScript development.
Every now and then (mostly on .js file open but also on some timer) I get the following popup error

```
    An internal error occurred during: "Synchronizing script resources with Tern server...".
    loader constraint violation: loader (instance of org/eclipse/osgi/internal/loader/EquinoxClassLoader) 
previously initiated loading for a different type with name "org/apache/http/HttpEntity"
```

I don't need Tern functionality and I would like to disable it or at least get rid of the popup error

I googled about but could not find any relevant information.
For the moment I tried to disable all validators and to change the .js editor but no luck by now.

Any idea?

Comment: Which version of tern.java do you use?

Comment: jdk1.7.0_51 (64bits) and Tern 0.8.2.201502201459

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it's the same problem than [issue 273](https://github.com/angelozerr/tern.java/issues/273) The 0.8.0 didn't set the version of packages of `org.apache.http` in the `MANIFEST.MF`.

Please [install 0.10.0 version](https://github.com/angelozerr/tern.java/wiki/Installation-Update-Site).

Comment: I could not install 0.10.0, because Tern.java 0.8.2 came with JBoss Tools 4.2.3 and it did not allow upgrade the version of Tern. However I reinstalled JBoss Tools without Java Standard Tools AngularJS and Java Standard Tools Tern.java Adapter and now I have neither Tern.java nor the error. Thank you for pointing the right direction

Comment: I was able to get rid of the error message by uninstalling the plugins JBoss Standard Tools AngularJS and Java Standard Tools Tern Java Adapter without reinstalling the whole JBoss Tools.

Comment: Why don't you post this as an answer?

Comment: I unstalled  JBoss Tools without Java Standard Tools AngularJS and Java Standard Tools Tern.java Adapter and the same problem exists. Is there anything else you have done?

Answer (score 1):

Go to Properties of the project > JavaScript > Include Path > Source and remove the whole project. Click on "Add Folder" and give the required path for your JS. Like projectname/src/pages.Ionic 2